# Random ordered k-subset sample algorithm reference

Tags: probability, algorithms

Let $k\leq n$ and we want to pick uniformly a size $k$ subset of $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$. Herbert S. Wilf gives an algorithm in here - https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/eastwest.pdf that does it (page 16 and function RandomKSubsets).

Important part of the algorithm is that it draws an ordered sample uniformly at random. This is the reason why reservoir sampling doesn't fit this problem, for example.

Does anybody know an alternative reference for the algorithm? A source that is peer-reviewed.